# What determines the required keys to sign in Corda?

Tags: corda

I recently got an error in my flow test that said:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A signature was requested for a key that isn't part of the required signing keys for transaction
```

When I look at my code I am having trouble tracking down which key is causing the problem.

The output state has a `participants` list on it.

The command takes a list of keys.

A local transaction is created that takes keys:

```
val locallySignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, keysToSignWith)
```

I'm also using the accounts SDK that has keys on each account.

The `CollectSignatureFlow` also takes a key of the counterparty.

Which part of this is it that determines the required keys to sign?

Answer (score 1):

In the below code block, the first parameter in `new Command()` is the type of command `Create()` and the second one is the list of required signers (in this case the lender and the borrower).
So to answer your question: the second parameter in the `Command` constructor defines the list of required signer.

```
final Command<IOUContract.Commands.Create> txCommand = 
new Command<>(new IOUContract.Commands.Create(), 
ImmutableList.of(iouState.getLender().getOwningKey(), iouState.getBorrower().getOwningKey()));
```

Please note that the contract of your state might have a validation rule that identifies who are supposed to be the required signers, so when you define the command above; if you request signers that are not supposed to be there, your contract will fail the verification:

```
require.using("All of the participants must be signers.", command.getSigners()
.containsAll(out.getParticipants().stream()
.map(AbstractParty::getOwningKey).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Now let's get back to your problem, I think what's happening is that you collected a signature from a party that's not part of the required signers on your command, I searched up Corda's code and found your error message coming from `CollectSignaturesFlow.checkMySignaturesRequired()` function:

```
private fun checkMySignaturesRequired(stx: SignedTransaction, signingKeys: Iterable<PublicKey>) {
    require(signingKeys.all { it in stx.tx.requiredSigningKeys }) {
        "A signature was requested for a key that isn't part of 
the required signing keys for transaction ${stx.id}"
    }
}
```

You mentioned that you're using the Accounts library, so my guess is that in your flow the host node (i.e. the node that hosts your accounts) must sign on behalf of them, so when it signs it should use the keys of those accounts, something like this:

```
getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder, Arrays.asList(pkOfAcc1, pkOfAcc2, pkOfAcc3);
```

I tried to answer to the best of my knowledge since I can't see your full code.